# change textView with string.xml resources in java class

Tags: java, android, xml

I wan't to set TextView's text with string values I have in string.xml

so I want to do this with switch-case in java class

**but it can't set text on my textView and when i run the app, the textview is empty**

sorry if it's a simple stupid mistake :)

this is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/shape">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:textColor="@color/txt_dialog"
    android:textSize="25sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is string.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="t1"> hi </string>
<string name="t2"> hello </string>
<string name="t3"> ok </string>
</resources>
```

and finally this is my java codes that should choose one of those strings whith random choice and then set that in textview in dialog

```
public void hi (){
    TextView txt_truth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
    Random random = new Random();
    int hi_random = random.nextInt(2) + 1;

    switch (hi_random){
        case 1:
            if (txt_truth != null) {
                txt_truth.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.t1));
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (txt_truth != null) {
                txt_truth.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.t2));}
            break;
        case 3:
            if (txt_truth != null) {
                txt_truth.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.t3));}
            break;}
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Obvious: `txt_truth.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.t1));` but your strings are named `a1, a2, ...`, not `t1, t2, ...`

Comment: sorry about that mistake, that occurred when i was writing that, i edited now

Comment: Also, if you are basing on this: `int hi_random = random.nextInt(45) + 1;` chances are that you are getting a number which is out of your switch range.

Comment: so sorry :) i copied codes from large project and i tried to make it more simple, but i missed some of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get the id of the textview from the dialog view inflation in this way

```
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    TextView txt_truth = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
```

Comment: @MohsenMohseni : ctx means context, you can pass this, depends where you are using

Answer (score 2):

> it can't set text on my textView and when i run the app, the textview
>   is empty

`string.xml` has only three strings which want to show in TextView randomly, but you are using `45` for getting Random number which generate number in range `[0-45]+1`.

get number between 1 to 3  as:

```
int hi_random = random.nextInt(2) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check the names of your String resources, are they a1 or t1 in series**

```
public void hi (){
TextView txt_truth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
Random random = new Random();
int hi_random = random.nextInt(45) + 1;

switch (hi_random){
    case 1:
        if (txt_truth != null) {
            txt_truth.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.a1));
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (txt_truth != null) {
            txt_truth.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.a2));}
        break;
    case 3:
        if (txt_truth != null) {
            txt_truth.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.a3));}
        break;}
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the top of my head I think the mistake is in your random generator. You have specified the upper value to be 45.

The nextInt(int n) method is used to get a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

```
int hi_random = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
```

Try the above code instead and comment whether it works or not.

You can also check the java doc on nextInt : [nextInt javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt())

Comment: `random.nextInt(3) + 1` this will give int as `1,2,3,4` but `4` is not in switch case

Comment: Its lower bound inclusive and upper bound exclusive. I have mentioned this in the answer